# Is it safe to delete files in the Staging > SharingProcesses directory in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro, is it safe to delete files in the Staging > SharingProcesses directory after a webmap or web layer has been published online?

I would assume that it is but I have some important web maps that are used by many users on the portal and I don't want to risk experimenting.